# web.xml init params more than one param-value

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, parameters

I would like to ask if it is possible to add more than one param-value in

```
<param-value>
```

tag?

For example:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the parameter. The code which reads the value can parse it in any way they like. This means there is no way for you to say "I want to pass multiple values" and no standard.

Spring doesn't support more than one class as `contextClass`. This class is used to build the application context and a Java class can always only have a single concrete type. If you don't specify the parameter, Spring will use `XmlWebApplicationContext` as default. If you use annotated Java config, then you will want to replace this with `org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.

The classes which configure Spring need to specified with `contextConfigLocation` which takes a list (comma and/or space separated) of file or class names.

For details, see the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-web and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

What you done is correct , it should be separated by comma `,` as the delimeter

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>ex1.com,ex2.com,.....</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or you can put them like below to make it more readable,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value> 
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
       org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

should work as expected

Comment: I think you meant `contextConfigLocation`; `contextClass` is the class which is used to build the application context and that can be only a single type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use several values in `<param-value>`, but only if method can accept array of values.

example 1:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>suffixExclusions</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsp, .ftl</param-value>
</init-param>
```

it works fine, because there can be many parameters.

example 2:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true, false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

will be an exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'forceEncoding'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [true, false]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:480)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1120)
```

cause method expect only one boolean value.

**UPD**

according [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html) expected only one class in parameter `contextClass`